# Receive mail from ERP software, change subject and forward

Tags: python, email, novell

im complete new to this so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Im already searching the whole day for a solution of our problem.

Our Problem: We create an order for our supplier using our ERP software. The supplier want a specific subject in this email to get the mail picked up by there order receive system. We can't set the subject in out ERP software.

Workaround: ERP is sending the mail to an internal address and then we need to change the subject and forward it to the supplier.

We want to do this automatically. is this possible?

I saw a few thing about Python to do this, but not the complete solution. So i know its maybe very nooby, but who can and want to help me.

We are using Novell mail server. (that's also complete new for me :-( )

Update: i've created some code, but its not the best. :)

```
import smtplib, imaplib, email, re
#mail read, change and forward
imap_host = "SERVERNAME"
client = imaplib.IMAP4('SERVERNAME')
client.login('USERNAME', 'PWD')
client.select('INBOX') #, readonly=True
msgid = 1
status, data = client.fetch(msgid, "(RFC822)")
email_data = data[0][1]
client.close()
client.logout()
message = email.message_from_string(email_data)
message.replace_header("Subject", "test")
message.replace_header("From", 'test@test.com')
message.replace_header("To", 'EXTERN EMAILADRES')
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('SMTP SERVER')
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('USERNAME', 'PWD')
from_addr = "AFZENDADRES"
to_addr = "EXTERN EMAILADRES"
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string())
#move mail to folder
client = imaplib.IMAP4('SERVERNAME')
client.login('USERNAME', 'PWD')
client.select('INBOX', readonly=False)
pattern_uid = re.compile('\d+ \(UID (?P<uid>\d+)\)')
def parse_uid(data):
match = pattern_uid.match(data)
return match.group('uid')
resp, items = client.search(None, 'All')
email_ids = items[0].split()
latest_email_id = email_ids[0]
resp, data = client.fetch(latest_email_id, "(UID)")
msg_uid = parse_uid(data[0])
result = client.uid('COPY', msg_uid, 'INBOX/Afgehandeld')
if result[0] == 'OK':
mov, data = client.uid('STORE', msg_uid , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
client.expunge()
client.close()
client.logout()
```

Should be fine if this code can be updates so that it checks if there are mails from a sender or with some words in the subject. if there aren't then stop the script. If there are 1 or more mails then we need to change the subject and forward the email to our supplier. Who can help me to get this code better.